# Local variable value changing after passing it to method

Tags: java, json, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, jsonnode

I am using `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode` java library to parse a `JSON` and perform some manipulation on the `JSON` string as follows -

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
{
    String jsonString = "{\"state\":{\"reported\":{\"deviceParams\":{\"deviceStatus\":{\"solenoid\":10,\"airFlow\":20}}}}}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    JsonNode jsonNode = null;
    try {
        jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonNode subNode = jsonNode.get("state").get("reported").get("deviceParams").get("deviceStatus");
    //Now subNode = {"solenoid":10,"airFlow":20}

    modifySubNode((ObjectNode) subNode);
    //type-casting JsonNode to ObjectNode since JSON manipulation like deletion and addition of nodes is only allowed in ObjectNode, not JsonNode
}

private static void modifySubNode(ObjectNode node) {
    if (node.get("solenoid") != null) {
        node.put("solenoid", 100);
    }
}
```

After the function call `modifySubNode()`, I expected the value of `jsonNode` to remain as

```
{
  "state":
  {
    "reported":
    {
      "deviceParams":
      {
        "deviceStatus":
        {
          "solenoid": 10,
          "airFlow": 20
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But instead, it became this

```
{
  "state":
  {
    "reported":
    {
      "deviceParams":
      {
        "deviceStatus":
        {
          "solenoid": 100,
          "airFlow": 20
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why is this happening ? I thought that any changes to "subNode" should not reflect on "`jsonNode`". Is there a mis-understanding on my part ?

Comment: I updated my answer regarding your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
jsonNode = mapper.readTree(deviceShadow);
```

That creates an **in memory** representation of your JSON data. Simply some sort of data structure that reflects the *structure* and content of your JSON string.

This here:

```
JsonNode subNode = jsonNode.get(...
```

then *traverses* that in-memory structure and identifies a sub-structure of it. Then you modify **that** substructure:

```
node.put("solenoid", 100);
```

And not surprisingly: when you modify that in-memory data structure, you modify your data!

In other words: your assumption is simply wrong. Imagine you have some standard Java Tree implementation that has a bunch of nodes. Now you identify a particular Node object within that tree, and change the value of that Node. Of course, that changes the content of the Tree as well, because that Node sits **inside** that Tree!

Long story short: you read data into memory, you specially target a certain part of that data, you change the data, the data is changed. That is all there is to this!

And just for the record: in the end, we are talking about the semantics of the underlying JSON library. The library you are using here ... simply doesn't copy or clone data when you ask for a sub node. It simply gives you a "pointer" right into the data. Other libraries might do that differently, one could imagine for example that all data is read only, and that modifications are done via returning a completely new Node object, decoupled from the initial data.

In order to not change the initial *jsonNode* object, the only option seems to be to parse your data **twice**. So create completely independent JsonNode by processing your input two times. Which of course doubles the amount of work that your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat ! Is there any way to change the "subNode" value without it reflecting on "jsonNode" ? I tried copying the value of "jsonNode" into another JsonNode object before manipulation but the changes were reflected in *that* new object as well.